# Python - How to get time difference from successive list

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Im creating a Flask app and have to pull timestamp data from a query to generate a report. What I've tried so far hasn't worked but this is as close as I've gotten.

```
employee = Employee.query.filter_by(id=id_num).first_or_404()
clocks = employee.clocks.all()
    for c in clocks:
        time = c.timestamp.strftime('%M')
        time = datetime.strptime(time, '%M')
        print(time)
        lis.append(time)
    res = [j - i for i, j in zip(lis[: -1], lis[1 :])]
    # ...Save the result and passs to html template
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you give an example of what sort of output you're expecting? `res = [j - i for i, j in zip(ls[:-1], ls[1:])]` should give you what you want

Comment: res should give me the difference of the pairs in the list. I have to query the data which puts the times into a list then get the differences by pairs. For example, list=[a, b, c, d] then get b-a and d-c.